# Generating tables using PHP

Tags: php

This code must generates a error-less table. Each cell displays file types of inside a certain directory. But there's a problem printing the table. It looks like this.
[image: table]

The whitespaces must be populated with data just like this

```
image      | image | image  
----------------------------
compressed | doc   | unknown
----------------------------
image      | image | image
```

This is my code:

```
<table border="1">

    <?php
    function identifyFile($file) {
        $file_pt = pathinfo($file);
        $file_ex = $file_pt['extension'];
        $images = array('jpeg','png','jpg','bmp');
        $docs = array('doc','docx','pdf','txt');
        $comp = array('rar','zip');
        if (in_array($file_ex,$images)){
            return "image";
        }
        elseif (in_array($file_ex,$docs)){
            return "doc";
        }
        elseif (in_array($file_ex,$comp)){
            return "compressed";
        }
        else {
            return "unknown";
        }
    }
    function svfilename($user_dir){
        $loops = 0;
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach (glob("$user_dir*.*") as $filename) {
            echo '<td>' .identifyFile($filename). '</td>';
            if($loops == 2) {
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                $loops = 0;
            }
            ++$loops;
            }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    svfilename("jfetz/");
    ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: What code are you talking about?

Comment: I forgot to put the codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incrementing loops after you set it to zero.

For the easy fix change `$loops = 0;` inside your `if($loops == 2) {` to `$loops = -1;`